# How do I comment object literals in YUIDoc

Tags: javascript, yui, javadoc

In YUIDoc, I want to comment object literals that are passed as parameters.  See the following snippet of code:

```
@param {Array} colDefs Array of object literal column definitions for the grid<ul>
    <li>title -  Column header display</li>
    <li>key -  The key of the column from the JSON data array</li>
    <li>type - The data type of the column.  </li></ul>
```

What tags do I add to list items so I can specify the type of property (String, Object, etc)?  If I add {String} it just shows up as the text, not the nice formatting that I get with @param tags.

Perhaps this is not even possible?

Comment: Found a workaround, but its a bit tedious to use:  <li>title <span class='type'>String</span><br>Column header display</li>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can document configuration objects by specifying first the configuration object and then all the properties as `object.property` parameters. It looks like this:

```
 /**
 @param {Object}  config          Object literal containing configuration parameters
 @param {Boolean} config.useFoo   Whether to use Foo or not
 @param {String}  [config.option] An optional string parameter
 */
```

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem!  I should read the documentation more closely, this was shown as an example but not explained clearly enough.